# Android onLocationchanged does not give correct time

Tags: android, google-play-services, locationmanager, ntp

I am using Google Play Service, to get the device's current location. My onLocationChanged() is getting called whenever there is a new location.

I am getting the latitude and longitude from the Location object in onLocationChanged(). These values are correct. But the time I am getting is not correct. It gives me the system time, which I have changed on purpose.

So is there any way for me to get the correct time. If the user has changed the device time for any reasons, I want a way to get the correct time.

I have checked NITZ/NTP threads as well, but it did not help. If I use SNTPClient, it gives me a correct time, but it creates a dependency of having internet connection.

I have tried by getting Location from both GPS and Network Provider. In both cases location is correct but the time is picked from the system. I have unchecked "Automatic time sync" on  my phone.

Comment: you change the time manually, you deny automatic sync, and you still want the correct time?...

Comment: Yes. Actually I want to have a tamper-proof solution. So if the user has unchecked the automatic sync and has changed the time, the back end should still get the "real" time and not the tampered one.

Answer (score 0):

Try Location.getTime(). 
It will return the UTC time of this fix, in milliseconds since January 1, 1970.

Note that the UTC time on a device is not monotonic: it can jump forwards or backwards unpredictably. So always use getElapsedRealtimeNanos when calculating time deltas. 
On the other hand, getTime is useful for presenting a human readable time to the user, or for carefully comparing location fixes across reboot or across devices. 
All locations generated by the LocationManager are guaranteed to have a valid UTC time, however remember that the system time may have changed since the location was generated.

Comment: Andrei, I am using Location.getTime() only. It gives an incorrect value of time. It picks the device time and not the time it receives from the GPS or network operator.

Answer (score 0):

location.getTime() gives you the Time THIS last updated value latitude/longitude is away from 1.1.1970 in ms.

14584084 or so